Ein/eine implicit with er/sie?
I have recently started learning German. As far as I have seen, there seems to be a one-one correspondence between German and English for many sentences. My question is

Er ist Kellner.
He is a waiter.
Er ist ein Kellner.

It appears that the former already translates to He is a waiter and the latter is probably redundant or even wrong. Why is there not a need for ein here? What about something like

Er ist nett.
He is nice.

This translation does not include an a. So I think an implicit assumption is going on here, but I would like some clarification. Does this happen anywhere else as well?

FYI, this 1:1 correspondence between English and German is only in beginner materials. You will find that they run out of those examples soon.

Just to expand on the comment, English and German are different languages with different grammar, expressions and idioms. Beginner texts tend to use examples where the there are fewer differences, but in "real" German it's not often the case. As an exercise, find some German text not written for learners, try to translate word for word, and see if it makes any sense. Chances are you'll discover there's a lot more to getting the meaning than just knowing the individual words.

I understand. Thanks for the insight!

You have found a special form of articles in German, called the "Nullartikel". This translates roughly to "null article" or "zero article" and can be seen as a word with a length of zero letters - so in effect, the article is left out. Though you probably could debate for hours whether a word with zero letters actually does exist or not ;)
There are some cases where the Nullartikel can be used, for example
Names, salutations and academic titles of people

Das musst Du Stefan fragen.
You have to ask Stefan about that.


Die Abteilung wird von Frau Müller geleitet.
The department is headed by Ms Müller.


Das neue Buch von Professor Schmidt ist sehr interessant.
The book by Professor Schmidt is very interesting.

Professions without further qualification

Er arbeitet als Kellner.
He works as a waiter.

but

Er ist ein erfahrener Taxifahrer.
He is an experienced cab driver.

The plural form of the indeterminate article

Ich lese ein Buch. -> Ich lese Bücher.
I read a book. -> I read books.

Names of countries, citys, continents, nationalities, ...

Ich reise nach Deutschland.
I travel to Germany.

Though there are some exeptions here:

Ich reise in die Schweiz.
I travel to Switzerland.

The use cases above are just examples, there are others. As you've probably seen in the examples, there are cases where the English language doesn't use an article either, while in other cases the handling differs between German and English. You can get quite into the weeds with the Nullartikel, especially when it comes to the exceptions of the rules.
Regarding your specific example,

Er ist Kellner.

and

Er ist ein Kellner.

are both grammatically correct and have just about the same meaning. There's a small difference in nuance: "Er ist Kellner" reads more like being a waiter is his profession, his calling in life maybe, while "Er ist ein Kellner" has more of a vibe of a job that maybe changed next month to something else.

It's not only professions, but some other categories as well. ("Er ist Franzose.", "Er ist Vegetarier.")

@Stefan It can also be applied to abstract qualities ("Ich habe Hunger") or materials ("Das Hemd ist aus Baumwolle"). As I mentioned, I only listed some examples for the usage of the Nullartikel, there are probably a bunch more.

"Professions without further qualification" - even this is misleading. "Er arbeitet als leitender Kellner." is fine, as "leitend" is a part of the job title here, even though structurally, it looks the same as the qualification "erfahren".

"Kellner" is a noun (and therefore should be capitalized BTW). Nouns can take articles, adjectives like "nett" cannot. This isn't any different from English.
"Er ist Kellner" and "Er ist ein Kellner" are both grammatical sentences with minimal (if any) difference in meaning.
